# Cannot close dialog on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried the following on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTqUr/)

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Hello.</p>
</div>

<a href="www.google.com">Link</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false }); 
    $(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();        
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    });  
});
```

I cannot close the dialog when I hit the close button. Why is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reopening the dialog when the close click bubbles up to the document level. The dialog close [x] is an `<a>` too.

Add this line to that "click" handler, at the very beginning:

```
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-dialog-titlebar-close')) return;
```

Alternatively, you could make your "open dialog" link more specific, by giving it a class or something:

```
    <a href=# class=open-dialog>Link</a>
```

Then:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.open-dialog', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
```

By making the link to open the dialog distinct from the close button, you get around the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You must define CLOSE function:

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Hello.</p>
</div>

<a id="open" href="www.google.com">Link</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });

    $(document.body).on('click',"#open",function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();        
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    });   

    $(document.body).on('click',".ui_icon_closethick",function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();        
        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
    }); 
});
```

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/QTqUr/1/